# XPath query for importing web content

Tags: xpath, web-scraping, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

Can anyone please suggest how to import '500112' and 'SBIN' from https://www.moneycontrol.com/india/stockpricequote/banks-public-sector/statebankindia/SBI in Google spreadsheet using importData or importXML functions?

Comment: I think the data you're looking is getting added dynamically, so the formula cannot retrieve it. Take a look at [this](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/115664/how-to-know-if-google-sheets-importdata-importfeed-importhtml-or-importxml-fun).

Comment: Hi, Nope this is a fixed value. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using

```
=IMPORTXML(A1,"//ctag[@class='mob-hide']//span") #where A1 is the url
```

this should get you both.

adding, for example:

```
=IMPORTXML(A1,"//ctag[@class='mob-hide']//span[1]")
```

at the end should output just

```
500112
```

Edit:

Since the question was asked, the site started using dynamically loaded data which GS can't handle. Using the tools in your browser's Developer tab, you can find out that the target data is loaded from a different site (see below) and that it is in json format.

So you need to use GS's `importJSON()` function for that:

```
A1 = https://priceapi.moneycontrol.com/pricefeed/bse/equitycash/SBI

A2 =importJSON(A1)
```

Make sure there's enough space on the sheet to expand the output. Once you do, you'll find the two target items under the columns `Data Bseid` and `Data Nseid`, probably in columns AL and AM.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the suggestion, but none of them are working. I just copy-pasted the exact formulae you suggested (except replacing the cell reference). Can you recheck if that working for you? Thanks in advance!

Comment: @RP-2020 Well, it definitely worked yesterday. Not today - the data is now loaded dynamically using javascript (maybe because of your question?) and GS can't handle that. There are scripts out there that may help you, or you may have to switch to a language that uses a tool like Selenium.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I see that the values in the webpage did not changed, and its still showing '500112' and 'SBIN'. Thse are the stock codes, so ideally these should never change. Is there some changes in the html code behind the scene?   (I am from a non-technical background, so my question may sound kiddish.) Thanks for your help.

Comment: Thanks so much. This was much more complicated than I ever thought, but your solution worked. This way I could import all the dynamic values in one go. Do you know if downloading data like this is legal?

Comment: @RP-2020 No idea about the legality; you can probably post it as a separate question to the legal board of Stack Exchange...

Comment: Thanks @Jack Fleeting. One more question. How do I identify the API link from where the data is flowing into the webpage.

Based on your suggestion for one webpage, I replaced the content and able to get the link for other pages. That worked for many pages, but not worked for all.  For eg:
https://www.moneycontrol.com/india/stockpricequote/banks-private-sector/axisbank/AB16
https://priceapi.moneycontrol.com/pricefeed/bse/equitycash/AB16   [Not working]

I tried to find the link in view-source of the webpage, but could not find it.

Comment: @RP-2020 That's a long and complicated story, but you can start, for example, here: https://ianlondon.github.io/blog/web-scraping-discovering-hidden-apis/.